# Facebook 'Send me email' Permission

Tags: facebook, permissions

I have question regarding facebook permissions.

I'm looking to let my website users 'Login with Facebook'. I've created an app however I want the user to explicitly agree to letting my app send them emails (see image below)

[image]

I've checked the facebook developers pages (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) and I can't seem to find a reference to the 'Send me email' permission that used to be available.

I can see it in the REST API documentation which has been deprecated but can't find it in the current documentation.

Any help on which permission to use would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ under the `User and Friends Permissions` section the last one is email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're setting up the permissions dialog via the [Enhanced Auth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/) (located in your app settings > Auth Dialog), simply use the 'email' permission as noted in the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#user_friends_perms) when configuring the User and Friends Permissions section.

If you are using the sdk to prompt a permissions dialog, just add 'email' to the comma separated list.

Comment: Thanks Brian, Will that present the 'Send me email' permission to the user? I'm asking because I want the end user to be able to opt out of marketing based emails from the application.

Comment: Yes, Facebook takes the permissions you request and presents them to the user during the authentication process. If you don't request additional permissions, the user is presented with a generic Auth dialog and you proceed with basic information. If you do, such as the 'email' permission, Facebook will allow them to opt out or to permit your app the use of information on a per permission basic. IE: email but not publish etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Brian. Very much appreciated!